# Error in R package that need C program to complie

Tags: r

I would like to work with R package SampleSizeBinomial_1.0.tar.gz.This package  includes a C program which will need be compiled. I am working in Windown 7 (64 bit) and I got the following error:

```
    > prop.acc(len=200, alpha=20.5, beta=18.5, level=0.95, exact=TRUE,     
     sim.size=1000, precision=1e-6, mcs=3)
     Error in .C("OutcomeEstimation", as.integer(n), as.double  
     (fixed.parm.target),  :  C symbol name "OutcomeEstimation" not in load table
```

How could i solve this problem? What should i do in this regards? All the information about this package and install instruction is [here](http://www.medicine.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/Joseph/software/Bayesian-Sample-Size.html).

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author?

Comment: No I have not tried since the SampleSizeBinomial_1.0.tar.gz. package is available which includes C program, but I do not know how to do it in Windows.

Comment: Works fine for me on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Did you follow all of the install instructions? http://www.medicine.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/Joseph/software/SampleSizeBinomial/README.html

Comment: If I install Ubuntu 14.04 , Does it mean it will automatically compile C program just by installing SampleSizeBinomial_1.0.tar.gz?

Comment: ... hahaha. Ok just... did you follow *all* of the install instructions? Do you have RTools installed?

Comment: When I do the DOS-prompt, type echo %path%, it is different from the author structure. I installed the RTools ,

Comment: It won't be the same but the only thing that matters is if the path to RTools shows up.  Does the path to Rtools show up when you type %path%?  Better yet why don't you show us the output from %path% by editing it into your question...